# Pool of objects with objects that are already on the scene in advance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote a pool of objects in which the objects were previously located on the stage, and in the script I made an array of objects, after which I pointed out references to the objects.
Could this somehow affect the performance of my mobile game?

The number of objects is about 360.

Objects are set to active = false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the profiler to check, but ultimately inactive objects only take up memory - processing cost is negligible.

In past there had been some corner cases related to having inactive objects parented to active objects that have their Transform change often, but this may not be an issue at this point. Still, parenting your pool objects to a separate object is good for organizational purposes (like not having to look at 300 things on the top level of your scene hierarchy view).